# How to get the the address of internal links in a webview

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

if an user clicks an internal link in the web view.i want to get its "href".my link is something like:

`<li><a href="RV://w_make27" style="color:#003366;">Click ME!!</a></li>`

As the link protocol is not http:// i am not getting the events (Navigating/navigated) fired

.please help me if anyone knows a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sujiz,

If I understand your question correctly, you are using a WebBrowser control to display a "web view" and want to capture the URLs that the user clicks on. Right?

If so, listen to the WebBrowser's Navigated/Navigating raised events & use the *WebBrowser.Source* property to get the URL that the browser component is loading.

This helps?

Comment: my link is something like :

<li><a href="RV://w_make27" style="color:#003366;">Click ME!!</a></li>


@samidip As the link protocol is not http:// i am not getting the events (Navigating/navigated) fired.

is there any work around for this issue.

Comment: Hmm .. so these links are not web resources. How is it not HTTP? Where does it take the user? I thought the webbrowser only displayed HTML & HTTP was the most common way to fetch content.

Comment: ya the links are not web resources.I want to get the value of the href that is here from the example "w_make27".I want this code to send next API

Comment: Sounds to me like using a WebBrowser control is a really terrible idea here. Parse the HTML, and present the user with a custom view, where you already parsed the HTML content.